# MongoDB / Express / React - How to define the variable name which will be saved in the db

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express

Im still new in coding and struggle on some basics.

I have to create a URL-Shortener with Express and MongoDB, additionally I use React for the frontent.

I have an input field and a submit button. The inputed URL will be sended by a POST request to the server.
(a console.log shows that this works fine)

Using "npm short-id"-package helps me to define an id for the shortUrl if the inputed url is accepted by "npm validid"- package.

Up to here, everything is fine.

Now, the "amateur-struggle" begins :)

I have learned the common pattern to save data in the mongoDB, example:

```
var createAndSaveUrl = function(done) {
  var NEEDHELP = new Url({url: req.body.url, shortUrl: shortid.generate()});

  NEEDHELP.save(function(err, data) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    done(null, data)
  });
};
```

The "NEEDHELP" variable makes me go crazy, because I think I have to give it a unique name for the DB but dont know how to do that.

Someone can help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var createAndSaveUrl = function(done) {   var shortenedUrl= new Url({url: req.body.url, shortUrl: shortid.generate()});

  shortenedUrl.save(function(err, data) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    done(null, data)   }); };
```

I think this is enough.

Comment: Okay, got it. But what happens after the first "shortenedUrl" has been saved and the next user inputs data? Will mongoDB overwrite the variable?

Comment: It will create a new entry, you have to call the above section in your get /post request of URL shortener

Comment: Okay, but will the variable name have an effect on the entry? Dont I have to define the "NEEDHELP" variable for every usage? Or can it allways be the same variable name?

Comment: nope the variable name is just a handle to your new Url object